# Dynamic configuration management

Tags: java, linux, scala, configuration-management

I'm looking for a tool or set of tools to manage configuration both for our scala application stack and other applications, e.g. lighttpd.

I've been thinking of using Apache Zookeeper, but I haven't found anything that looks like a module for lighttpd (and possibly others). I also considered using for example Puppet, but there doesn't seem to be much of a Zookeeper module for it.

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to have one service that keeps configuration & that I can reconfigure dynamically and that would propagate to all services, both on and off the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, pick one of the [Open Source Configuration Management Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software). One interesting choice that have recently appear and is not listed on Wiki is [ANSIBLE](http://ansible.github.com/).

Also, your problem might be one of orchestration, in which case tools like Chef's [Knife](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Knife), [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki), [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/index.html) or [MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/) are more adequate.

It might even be you want both, of course.

The best choice would be one written in a language you are familiar with. I don't know of any written in Scala, though [this blog post](http://kafecho.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/thought-exercise-scala-features-for.html) is interesting. For programmers, [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) has great attraction, and handles very dynamic configurations well. I know someone who uses it to create/destroy VM instances on-demand, depending on the application load -- try that with Puppet, and you'll cry.

I like [Puppet's](http://puppetlabs.com/) declarative configuration style, and in particular the fact that it insulates you a lot from the Operating System differences. To Puppet, a Package is a Package, no matter what operating system you are using.

As for "Zookeeper module"... you might find good recipes/modules for these tools online, but you better be prepared to write your own. Do not chose based on the existence of one particular module -- chose based on how comfortable you feel writing them.

Comment: Thanks! ANSIBLE looks promising, I'll have a shot at it.